# Rosjava + (OpenCV) => (2D to 3D)

Tags: opencv, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want compute 3D position from 2D point of video-stream (from Kinect) in rosjava. I know that, is possible in roscpp/rospy, because existed CV_Bridge and after I can compute 3D position by OpenCV library.

My question, Is something similar possible in rosjava ? or I have to compute manualy ?

Thank for any advice

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56523/rosjava-+-(opencv)-=%3E-(2d-to-3d)/) by [LeopoldPodmolík](https://answers.ros.org/users/3844/leopoldpodmol%C3%ADk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fei](https://answers.ros.org/users/22709/fei/) on 2015-06-08**:
Could you please tell me which function you use from openCV library to compute 3D position. I am doing the similar work with yours. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you take a look at [OpenCV now supports desktop Java](http://www.willowgarage.com/blog/2013/02/19/opencv-now-supports-desktop-java)?

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0